# Add key and dictionary as key-value pair into existing dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I'd like to add
"5f6c" as a key with values as photo_dict = {'caption': 'eb test', 'photo_id':'330da114-e41e-4cee-ba15-f9632'} into the below using python. I am not sure how to go about it

```
  {'record': {'status': 'bad', 'form_id': '16bba1', 'project_id': None, 'form_values': {'5121': 
 'yes', '8339': 'ZTVPNG', '6cd3': '234624', '6b5b': '105626', 'e1f6': '[]', '5f6c': [{'id': 
 'f6efe67d7c5', 'created_at': '1614189636', 'updated_at': '1614189636', 'form_values': {'4ba6': 
  'Gaaaaah!'}}}
```

Such that the dictionary becomes

```
       {'record': {'status': 'bad', 'form_id': '16bba1', 'project_id': None, 'form_values': {'5121': 
    'yes', '8339': 'ZTVPNG', '6cd3': '234624', '6b5b': '105626', 'e1f6': '[]', '5f6c': [{'id': 
   'f6efe67d7c5', 'created_at': '1614189636', 'updated_at': '1614189636', 'form_values': {'4ba6': 
     'Gaaaaah!', '5f6c': [{'caption': eb test, 'photo_id': '330da114-e41e-4cee-ba15-f9632'}]}}}
```

Comment: this is an invalid dictionary. include the full dictionary in your post.

Comment: Please make your question clearer. Your dictionary isn't valid and there is nested dictionaries here, and things are really messy and confusing. For shallow dict I tend to do things in line but after a few levels of nesting I would be formatting it better for readability. To add a key value pair to any dict you can just do ```my_dict['Key'] = 'value'```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems your initial dictionary is incorrectly formed and does not fully match what you are asking in the question, I would start by updating it with a correct format .

That being said, I ll assume the format would be close to this:

```
{
    "record":{
        "status":"bad",
        "form_id":"16bba1",
        "project_id":"None",
        "form_values":{
            "5121":"yes",
            "8339":"ZTVPNG",
            "6cd3":"234624",
            "6b5b":"105626",
            "e1f6":"[]",
            "5f6c":[
                {
                    "id":"f6efe67d7c5",
                    "created_at":"1614189636",
                    "updated_at":"1614189636",
                    "form_values":{
                        "4ba6":"Gaaaaah!",
                        "5f6c": {
                                "caption":"eb test",
                                "photo_id":"330da114-e41e-4cee-ba15-f9632"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You want to modify 5f6c with value

```
{'caption': 'eb test', 'photo_id':'330da114-e41e-4cee-ba15-f9632'}
```

Its not very clear which key you actually want to modify as the key 5f6c can be found in two different place in your dict, but it seems what you are trying to do is just modify a dictionary.

So  what you need to take away from this is that to modify a dictionary and list you simply do

```
myDict[key] = value
myList[indice] = value
```

You contact as much as you want the operation in the same line.

If we take your example from above, and try to modify the most narrowed value, it would give us

```
import json
records = json.loads(theString)
records['record']['form_values']['5f6c'][0]['form_values']['5f6c'] = {"caption":"eb test", "photo_id":"330da114-e41e-4cee-ba15-f9632"                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After correcting your formatting I would do this.

```
my_dict = {'record': {'status': 'bad', 
            'form_id': '16bba1', 
            'project_id': None, 
            'form_values': {'5121': 'yes', 
                            '8339': 'ZTVPNG', 
                            '6cd3': '234624', 
                            '6b5b': '105626', 
                            'e1f6': '[]', 
                            '5f6c': [{'id': 'f6efe67d7c5', 
                                      'created_at': '1614189636', 
                                      'updated_at': '1614189636', 
                                      'form_values': {'4ba6': 'Gaaaaah!'}
                                      }
                            ]}
            }
}

photo_dict = {'caption': 'eb test', 'photo_id':'330da114-e41e-4cee-ba15-f9632'}

                                                                                   

my_dict['record']['form_values']['5f6c'][0]['form_values']['5f6c'] = photo_dict
```

By the way you can get tools in your IDE that will help you with formatting and handle it for you.